# Automatically size TextBlock length to length of characters (in a Grid)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Grid that I populate with a TextBlock and another Grid, which is initially hidden. Since I have the TextBlock to respond to click events, I only want the method to be called when the user clicks on the text itself, not anywhere in the Grid. This is what my code looks like right now:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="25">
    <TextBlock x:Name="NewLabelButton" Text="Add New" Width="Auto" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddNew_OnClick" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid x:Name="NewLabelPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameBox" TextChanged="NameBox_OnTextChanged" KeyDown="NameBox_OnKeyDown" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_OnClick" IsEnabled="False" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_OnClick" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Which results in the TextBlock spanning the whole width of the Grid, making it clickable from essentially anywhere in the Grid. What I want is for it to only be as wide as it needs to be to display the text (which could vary, so I can't use a static width).

Using a StackPanel instead of a Grid resolves the TextBlock width issue, but then the child Grid doesn't expand to fill the entire StackPanel, which it needs to.

Encapsulating the TextBlock in a StackPanel works, but I'm wondering if there is a better (and more efficient) way of doing it.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="25">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="NewLabelButton" Text="Add New" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddNew_OnClick" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="NewLabelPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
```

So my question is this: Is there a better way to do this than with my little StackPanel hack, or is that the only way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `TextBlock` to the left of the grid.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="NewLabelButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Add New" Width="Auto" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddNew_OnClick" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thanks!